# Why does putting a INDIRECT inside WEEKNUM return "#VALUE"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have tried this on both the Mac and Windows version of Excel. They both return #value. Any ideas of how to fix this?

```
=WEEKNUM(INDIRECT("C[1]",0),2)
```

When I evaluate the formula:

[image: When I evaluate the formula] ,

Example of What is happening:

[image: Example of What is happening]

Comment: It looks like you are indirecting the cell itself? are you sure the data in D cell is a date?

Comment: Two possibilities jump out.  1) Your R1C1 referencing looks like it's evaluating to the entire column.  WEEKNUM needs a single cell reference.  Try including the R, like "RC[1]", and see if that fixes it.  2) The date looks left justified and is in the day/month/year sequence.  That's a locale-based standard.  If that is not standard for you, Excel may be reading that as text, which would produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use *Weeknum()* with *Indirect()*.

In **B1** enter:

```
=TODAY()
```

In **C1** enter the text:

```
B1
```

In **A1** enter the formula:

```
=WEEKNUM(INDIRECT(C1))
```

[image]